# .NET 5 Unit Test project VS 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

When I go to add a unit test project from VS 2019 I see a lot of templates for .Net Framework and .Net Core but I don't see any for .Net 5? Is there a template available? Or is there a work-around?

[image]

Comment: ".NET 5" **IS** .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alejandro is correct.  Keep in mind if you add a test project it will default to targeting .net core 3.1 (or mine does) and so if you add a project reference to a .net 5.0 project you will have to change the target framework to .net 5.0 for the test project.

Comment: Thank you. I thought .NET 5 was the unifying framework which is why it doesn't have the name .NET 5 Core. But I guess this makes sense since it is .NET Core and so much more>